# Jackson not properly mapping properties to POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson

Been trying to map a certain JSON string that I'm receiving from an REST API call, but so far I only got the following message.

`Unrecognized field "my_first_field" (class MyClass), not marked as ignorable`

I've been parsing the contents with `IOUtils` class, the following way (maybe the encoding is the root cause).

`String json = IOUtils.toString(responseEntity.getContent(), UTF_8);`

Once this has been done, I try to map the payload String to my POJO class using `ObjectMapper`.

`new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<MyClass>(){  })`

However, while performing that step the exception mentioned in the beginning is prompt. The POJO class is the following.

```
public static class MyClass {

    @JsonProperty("my_first_field")
    private List<Map<String, String>> myFirstField;
    @JsonProperty("my_second_field")
    private String mySecondField;

    public MyClass() { }

    public MyClass(List<Map<String, String>> myFirstField, String mySecondField) {
        this.myFirstField = myFirstField;
        this.mySecondField = mySecondField;
    }

    (...)

}
```

Ignoring those unknown fields result in all POJO fields being null. What could be the problem in here?

**EDIT**: Sample JSON

```
{"my_second_field":"samplevalue", "my_first_field":[{"inner":"value"}]}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you attach your json, so we can reproduce your use case and help you.

Comment: Make sure you import `@JsonProperty` annotation from fasterxml package, not from anywhere else.

Comment: Looks like you have problems with your string. Just check  your `json` variable first

Comment: @SpasojePetronijević just updated my question.

Comment: @AlanSereb it was that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you import `@JsonProperty` annotation from fasterxml package, not from anywhere else.